# Pulseaudio controls wrong volume bar - Xonar DSX

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm using Archlinux with my Xonar DSX.
My problem happens when I want to use my headphones, I just open Pulseaudio, in the Configuration tab I select the profile for analog output and so far so good. My headphones are working perfectly.

But if I want to change the volume, using Pulseaudio nothing *seems* to change, except for when I set volume to 0% (in this case it mutes the headphones). Using alsamixer from terminal I noticed that there are many volume columns (Master Front, Master Rear, Master Center, Master Woofer, Master Side, Headphones).
Pulseaudio is changing the Headphones column, but as I said this doesn't truly change volume output, changing Master Front does.

How can I tell Pulseaudio to bind the Master Front column instead of the Headphones one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Bug 93224: Volume control not working with Asus Xonar DS and PulseAudio 7](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93224)

Comment: I don't know how I didn't found it googling. My bad.
It helped a lot, thanks @CL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @CL, there is a bug using Pulseaudio 7 (in the Asus driver as far as I know). You can find it here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93224

There is a workaround to fix the problem: simply remove *(not deleting the file)* the content of `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`.

To do so:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf.backup
$ sudo touch /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf
```

Restart you computer and you're done.
I hope it will help somebody.

Comment: Such little things cause so much problems sometimes :) Yep worked as expected. Too bad its still not fixed months later :/